# Field returns empty string

Tags: profile, lotus, lotusscript

I create a new profile document with the following code:

```
Set doc = db.Createdocument()
doc.Form = "SMBPrivateProfile"
Call doc.Computewithform(True,True)
Call doc.Save(True, False)
```

But whenever I want to read a field by `@GetProfileField` i get an empty string, even if the field I want to read has a default value.
After opening & saving the document manually everything works.

---

Further details:
I improved an application and hit `Application --> Replace Design...`. The new version includes a new field within the profile document. When reading one of these new fields, the result is an empty string. When reading an 'old' field within the same document the result is the expected string.

e.g.:

```
MessageBox([OK];"Title"; @GetProfileField("SMBPrivateProfile"; "OLD_FIELD"; @ThisName))
```

--> Will result in: "This is a fancy old default value"

```
MessageBox([OK];"Title"; @GetProfileField("SMBPrivateProfile"; "NEW_FIELD"; @ThisName))
```

--> Will result in: "" (instead of "This is a fancy new default value")

Answer (score 3):

That's not a profile document. To create profile document use:

```
db.GetProfileDocument("SMBPrivateProfile");
```

You can also add a second parameter for a unique key in addition to profile name.

Also consider if you really want to use profile documents. They are heavily cached and not visible in any views.

Comment: I replaced my first two lines with your suggestion. But now an error appers in line: `Call doc.Computewithform(True,True)` 'Incorrect datatype. Number expected' But when I replace the booleans with integers the same error pops up.
However I still cannot read any value from the profile document (even when dropping the whole line about the `computewithform`)

Comment: @Markus I've never thought about computing a profile doc with form. It may not work. The problem to get the value may because of the cache. Try to get it also with the same `db.GetProfileDocument("SMBPrivateProfile");`.

Comment: I can't think of a reason why ComputeWithForm shouldn't work in a profile doc.  The error 'incorrect datatype. Number expected' at least indicates that it's trying to work, but a formula is returning a bad result.  Markus: if you want to keep using ComputeWithForm for this, you might want to try using @CommandEditProfile to bring the profile doc up in the Notes client UI and then try saving it to see if you get the same error.  If it does, then you'll have to go through the usual pain of debugging formula errors to find the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading you right, it appears that you have updated a form and added a new field with a default value formula.  You are then reading an existing document.  When you do this, the new field that you added to the form does not yet exist.  New fields and formulas aren't applied to existing documents until you do something to force them to be applied.

If it's a regular document (as your original code indicated), you can just open the document in the Notes client, edit, and re-save it.  That will create the NEW_FIELD and give it its value.  If there are lots of these documents, you could write a simple formula agent to do this via `@Command([ToolsRefreshAllDocs])` or `@Command( [ToolsRefreshSelectedDocs])`.

If it is a profile document (as per the responce chain to @Panu's anser), then after you do the replace design you will have to write an agent to open the existing profile document using `db.getProfileDocument` use doc.ReplaceItemValue("NEW_FIELD";"new value").